# Webpack code splitting loading paths

Tags: webpack, webpack-4

I am splitting my code using the webpack `import()` based on some configuration files as below:

```
setClientId({commit}, clientId) {
  return import(`@/configs/client.${clientId}.js`).then((configImport) => {
    const config = configImport.default
    commit('setClientId', clientId)
    commit('setClientConfig', config)
    commit('syncClientDefaultsToUserObject', config.defaults)
  })
}
```

I have setup the `@` as an alias for resolve within webpack:

```
  resolve : {
    alias : { '@': path.resolve('client')}
  },
```

Which works fine on my local and when the app is deployed on the same domain - now the issue is that the app is deployed on various domains from a single server.

So the initial request goes to `myserver.com/app.bundle.js` which works fine, but then the split code is requested from `websiteOnWhichDeployed.com/codesplit.bundle.js`

Help!